# Cannot access SMB share on Windows Server 2003 from Windows CE 6.0 device

Tags: windows-ce, windows-server-2003, smb, motorola-emdk

I'm attempting to write a file to an SMB share using FileStream.  Whenever I attempt this, I get a login dialog asking for username, password and domain.  I enter these details and click OK, but it box comes back up.  I enter details for another user that I know has access.  The same happens.  After the third attempt, my application pops up with an IOException and breaks.

I know the credentials I'm using are correct... but something's not working as it should.

My device is a Motorola MC3190.

Any suggestions much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple - set the time and date on the SMB client!!

Answer (score 0):

I would check and make sure the WINS Service is running on the 2003 server.

Comment: It was even easier than that, Chris.  I just set the time and date on the device :).